# Semi Circle in Tableau Start at 270 and not 0

Tags: tableau-api

I have many calculated fields that come up with a percentage based on the number of days payment was made. I am using those calculated fields in place of the parameter [Percentage]. There is no number identifier to associate as instructed on the following website.  I have the calculations done, the case statement and the color field. There is no Number Identifier, so I have no [SLICE#]
https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2018/01/percentage-gauges-in-tableau_61.html

I have a 96.02% and it always starts at 0 or 12 o'clock. I need it to start at 270. SAnd "Hidden" or "None" does not work in the Color Field.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up duplicating my calculations and for each, I did for [Payment % 1 of 2]

```
   IF([Payments] / [Total  Default]) > .5 Then 
  ( Payments] / [Total Default]) - .5 
ELSE [Payments] / [Total Default] END
```

and for [Payment % 2 of 2]

```
IF( Payments] / [Total Default]) > .5 Then 
 ([Payments] / [Total Default]-[Payment % 1 0f 2])
ELSE [Payment % 1 0f 2] END
```

And then just reorder them and make them the same color.
While having a calculation of 1 at the bottom